# Trigger Warning message

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I am pretty new when it comes to SQL and I am currently working on triggers and I have a trigger i am not sure what the problem is. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out what is wrong. Truthfully I am not even sure if this is a good trigger or not. I am having a little trouble with them. Thank you. I appreciate it.

Trigger to raise error on new purchase or updated purchase

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reminder1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PurchasedDeal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( 'Notify new Purchased Deal Created or updated' );
END;
```

All it is saying is this:

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Comment: I won't ask why you'd want to do this, but try adding an error code:  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Notify new Purchased Deal Created or updated' );

Comment: What tool are you using for your development? It's pretty crucial that you get comfortable with displaying compilation errors, otherwise you will be stuck every time anything doesn't compile first time. Also your [raise_application_error](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1) is missing an error code. There is no need to code in uppercase, even though a lot of examples are written that way. Personally I see it as a widespread bad habit.

Comment: When faced with a compilation error your first port of call should be the documentation. The Oracle doc set is online, comprehensive and free. It's worth bookmarking. Here is the entry for [`raise_application_error()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#GUID-48F88C61-8CE9-4821-91CB-48A8F1BC09E1)

Comment: *"Truthfully I am not even sure if this is a good trigger or not."* It's a bad trigger, in the sense that it prevents any insert or update of that table (raising an exception issues a rollback) although the "error" message seems to imply that the statement has succeeded.

Comment: I also feel like this is a bad trigger, but does anyone have an idea what trigger I could make that is better? Thank you

Comment: @Matt - *Does anyone have an idea what trigger I could make that is better?* What is the business requirement?

Comment: @Matt - it may be an idea to read "Reasons to use triggers" (see: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS723 ), and to try out (and modify) the code listed "Creating a Trigger that Logs Table Changes" section located @ https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG52100.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which software you are using for developing your PL/SQL code.  However, you should find out how to make the "compilation error" messages visible eg

using sqlcl (command line tool)

```
-- just a test table ...
create table purchaseddeal ( id )
as
select 1 from dual ;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER reminder1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PurchasedDeal
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( 'Notify new Purchased Deal Created or updated' );
END;
/

SQL> show error

Errors for TRIGGER ...REMINDER1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/1      PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR'
```

When using https://livesql.oracle.com you'll get

```
-- this will be displayed straightaway after compiling ...
Errors: TRIGGER REMINDER1 
Line/Col: 2/1 PL/SQL: Statement ignored 
Line/Col: 2/1 PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR'
```

Then, you can find out more by looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960).

> RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR Procedure
>
> You can invoke the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR procedure (defined in the
>   DBMS_STANDARD package) only from a stored subprogram or method.
>   Typically, you invoke this procedure to raise a user-defined exception
>   and return its error code and error message to the invoker.
>
> To invoke RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, use this syntax:
>
> RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (error_code, message[, {TRUE | FALSE}]); You
>   must have assigned error_code to the user-defined exception with the
>   EXCEPTION_INIT pragma. The syntax is:
>
> PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (exception_name, error_code) The error_code is
>   an integer in the range -20000..-20999 and the message is a character
>   string of at most 2048 bytes.

It is problably not obvious (to yourself or other programmers) why you would use a procedure called RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR when things go to plan ie when a row was successfully INSERTed or UPDATED.  Maybe the following example is a better illustration of what you wanted to code (or see):

**Table: purchaseddeal**

```
SQL> select * from purchaseddeal ;

PRODUCT_ID        QTY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100
```

**Trigger**

```
-- fires when a price is too high or too low 
-- (this could also be coded as a CHECK constraint - but the question is about triggers ...).

create or replace trigger checktheprice
  before insert or update on purchaseddeal
  for each row
begin
  if :new.price < 0 then
    raise_application_error( -20000, 'Price too low' ) ;
  elsif :new.price > 1000 then
    raise_application_error( -20001, 'Price too high' ) ;
  end if;
end ;
/
```

**Testing**

```
SQL> insert into purchaseddeal values ( 2, 20, 2000 ) ;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into purchaseddeal values ( 2, 20, 2000 )
Error report -
ORA-20001: Price too high
ORA-06512: at "...CHECKTHEPRICE", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '...CHECKTHEPRICE'

SQL> insert into purchaseddeal values ( 2, 20, -2000 ) ;

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into purchaseddeal values ( 2, 20, -2000 )
Error report -
ORA-20000: Price too low
ORA-06512: at "...CHECKTHEPRICE", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '...CHECKTHEPRICE'
```

**The table is still untouched ...**

```
select * from purchaseddeal ;

SQL> select * from purchaseddeal ;

PRODUCT_ID        QTY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100
```

**Anonymous block and PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT**

```
declare
  price_too_low  exception ; 
  price_too_high   exception ;
-- assign the error_codes to the user-defined exceptions
  pragma exception_init( price_too_low, -20000 ) ;
  pragma exception_init( price_too_high, -20001 ) ;
begin
  insert into purchaseddeal values ( 2, 20, 2000 ) ;
--  insert into purchaseddeal values ( 2, 20, -2000 ) ;
exception 
  when price_too_low then 
    dbms_output.put_line( to_char( sqlerrm( -20000 ) ) ) ;
  when price_too_high then
    dbms_output.put_line( to_char( sqlerrm( -20001 ) ) ) ;
end ;
/ 

-- output
ORA-20001: Price too high
ORA-06512: at "...CHECKTHEPRICE", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '...CHECKTHEPRICE'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Some more testing: values in allowed range**

```
-- insert some rows that contain values in the allowed range
insert into purchaseddeal ( product_id, qty, price )
select 
  level + 1, ( level + 1 ) * 10, ( level + 1 ) * 100.00
from dual
connect by level <= 8 ;
```

**The table now contains ...**

```
SQL> select * from purchaseddeal ;

PRODUCT_ID        QTY      PRICE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100
         2         20        200
         3         30        300
         4         40        400
         5         50        500
         6         60        600
         7         70        700
         8         80        800
         9         90        900

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: As you went to all the trouble of providing various error outputs, you might as well complete the task by showing the correct solution. I know you have provided a link  but that doesn't qualify as an answer.

Comment: @Stefan Read the comments above. `raise_application_error` has missing code so modify your answer with  `raise_application_error (-20034,'Notify new Purchased Deal Created or updated');`